# How can I overwrite a application.yml in a class attribute?

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I have this property in my properties yml file:

```yaml
jackson:
    default-property-inclusion: non_null
    serialization:
        write-empty-json-arrays: false
    serialization-inclusion: NON_EMPTY
```

What it does is prohibit JSON empty arrays. But for a specific attribute in a class, I want to be able to return it empty. Is there a way or property I can use to make this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way would be to create another `ObjectMapper` and then use that one to serialize that specific class.

```kotlin
@Configuration
class JacksonConfiguration {

    @Bean
    fun mainObjectMapper() = jacksonObjectMapper().apply {
        setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
        setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
    }

    @Bean
    fun otherObjectMapper() = jacksonObjectMapper().apply {
        setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    }
}
```

However, this seems a little bit overkill for such a simple thing.

---

Another option, which is maybe the best for you is to use the `@JsonInclude` annotation. You would use it as follows:

```java
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)
List<String> propertyToSerializeEvenIfEmptyOrNull;
```

Comment: Hey, Joao! Thanks for your time! I've tried using @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS), but it seems like the property file overwrites it. So, the only option would be through objectMapper?

Comment: Then I would say yes.

Comment: Just one more question: how should I call the objectMapper to the class?

Comment: It depends on how you are serializing the objects of that class.